# Select specific attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
#<Example example_id: 13, example2_id: 81, year: 2000, january: 12, february: 3, march: 3, april: 4, may: 5, june: 2, july: 4, august: 24, september: 4, october: 24, november: 4, december: 4>
```

I want to put the values of months in a array like this:

```
array_example = [12, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 24, 4, 24, 4, 4]
```

I know I can do this (example below) but I want a better way.

```
   example.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
      if attr_name == "january" || attr_name == "february" || attr_name == "march" ||
         attr_name == "april" || attr_name == "may" || attr_name == "june" ||
         attr_name == "july" || attr_name == "august" || attr_name == "september" ||
         attr_name == "october" || attr_name == "november" || attr_name == "december"
                    @array_example << attr_value
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Hash#values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) is for exactly this:

```
example.attributes.values_at(:january, :february, :march, :april, :may, :june, :july, :august, :september, :october, :november, :december)
# => [12, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 24, 4, 24, 4, 4]
```

It's probably best to put the month names in a constant (e.g. in your Example model), if only for readability, e.g.:

```
MONTH_ATTRS = %i[ january   february  march     april
                  may       june      july      august
                  september october   november  december ]
# Or...
MONTH_ATTRS = Date::MONTHNAMES.drop(1).map {|m| m.downcase.to_sym }
```

(The latter uses Ruby's built-in [`Date::MONTHNAMES`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#constants-list) constant; [`drop(1)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-drop) is necessary because `Date::MONTHNAMES[0]` is `nil`, presumably so January will be at index 1.)

Then:

```
example.attributes.values_at(*Example::MONTH_ATTRS)
```

P.S. If you would rather have a hash than an array, you can use [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) from ActiveSupport:

```
example.attributes.slice(*Example::MONTH_ATTRS)
# => { :january => 12,  :february => 3, :march => 3,    :april => 4,
#      :may => 5,       :june => 2,     :july => 4,     :august => 24,
#      :september => 4, :october => 24, :november => 4, :december => 4 }
```

P.P.S. If you're not using the model object for anything else—i.e. you just want the month values and nothing else, you should use [`ActiveRecord::Calculations#pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) in your query, e.g.:

```
Example.where(...).pluck(*Example::MONTH_ATTRS)
```

`pluck` tells ActiveRecord to just return the values of those attributes, instead of instantiating and returning an Example model object.

Answer (score 0):

```
months = %w(january february march) 
months.include? attr_name
```

Comment: As it's every month name it might be easiest to use Date's month names constant `months = Date::MONTHNAMES.reject(&:nil?).map(&:downcase)`

Answer (score 0):

```
monthnames = %w(january february march april may june july august september october november december)
example_attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
  if monthnames.include?(attr_name)
    @array_example << attr_value
  end
end
```

OR

```
@array_example += monthnames.collect{|monthname| example.attributes[monthname]}.reject(&:blank?)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MONTHS = %w( january february march april may june july august september october november december )

example.attributes.slice(*MONTHS)
=> {january: 12, february: 3, march: 3, april: 4, may: 5, june: 2, july: 4, august: 24, september: 4, october: 24, november: 4, december: 4}
example.attributes.slice(*MONTHS).values
=> [12, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 24, 4, 24, 4, 4]
```